# Baking course online

Tags: baking

I want to learn baking and have been reading recipes from the internet and trying them but, I want a more structured approach starting with the basics and going to the advanced. I don't feel that the ad-hoc method of reading recipes and executing them is very satisfying. In my country, we don't bake a lot except for the professional pastry chefs. So, I don't know of anyone who's a baker or any baking classes around my home. So, does anyone know of an online baking course?

Comment: It's not free, but rouxbe, which is a very high quality on line cooking school, includes baking lessons.

Comment: rouxbe is great, but their baking lessons are pretty basic

Comment: Just go to [youtube](http://www.youtube.com) . There are thousands of baking videos available. Not all are great, but some definitely are very useful. You also have a lot of video posters that refer to their website with more baking videos.

Comment: If there were a million of these and this was a survey, I could see this being a bad fit for us - but there really aren't very many, especially good ones, on the net.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to find handbooks or informational sites than classes specifically, as the former can be put up once and left there, whereas the latter requires a teacher be present for each iteration of the course.

I found a good bread-making handbook at [The Fresh Loaf](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/handbook); they also have [lessons](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/lessons) on specific topics. Prepared Pantry has a free [baking cookbook](https://www.preparedpantry.com/how-to-bake-free-cook-book.htm) as well, plus [lessons](https://www.preparedpantry.com/baking-lessons.htm), though their classes are done I believe at their store location.

Comment: +1 - Its tough to beat the Fresh Loaf for strictly bread stuff - its a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try Carole Walter's on-line baking school. On-line courses are only as good as the people teaching them. Carole is a master of home baking and teaching. With four award-winning books and numerous other accolades -- Carole is a teacher above all else. You will learn to do things her way -- and that's delicious perfection!